# This code gives me all the months and numbers of the year. How can I make the numbers not being the same

Tags: python

```
month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", 
"May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December"]
num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]

for i in range(len(month)):
  for h in range(len(num)):
    print(month[i], "the", num[h])
```

How can I fix the numbers so that some months are 28th and some are the 31st? Currently all of the months are up to the 31st.

Comment: Use the calendar module? - https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html

Comment: What you want is some lookup table. https://w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: Can somebody help edit or add to this code to help out please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd go about it while sticking with the way you're basically going about the problem:

```
month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

month_days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

is_leap_year = True

for i in range(len(month)):
    for h in range(29 if (month_days[i] == 28 and is_leap_year) else month_days[i]):
        print(month[i], "the", h + 1)
```

Note that there was really no need to list every day number in a list.  Also, see how I dealt with leap-years.  It will add an extra day to February when `is_leap_year == True`.